# Android Studio Layout Inspector not working

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

I'm new to android studio and I just learnt how to use inspector. I just clicked "hide subtree" of the webview mistake and afterthat the inspector turned blue. I tried to restart and it did not help. Can anyone help me digest this? Thank you in advance!

[image]